# rxjs: Observble.pipe is not function

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I created a project using VS2017 angular2 template. I am trying to use angular/material in my angular2 App. There is an error

> this._control.stateChanges.pipe is not a function
>
> at MatFormField.ngAfterContentInit (form-field.es5.js:327)

Seems that the pipe function of Observable is missing. Is this my config problem or rxjs updated? Here is my Config:

```
 "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "5.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
"@angular/common": "5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "5.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "5.0.0",
"@ngtools/webpack": "1.8.0",
"@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
"angular-router-loader": "^0.7.0",
"angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
"aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
"devextreme": "^17.1.8",
"devextreme-angular": "^17.1.8",
"jquery": "3.2.1",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
"rxjs": "5.5.2",
"typescript": "2.6.1",
"webpack": "https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack/-/webpack-2.5.1.tgz",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.12"
}
```

**Update**
I found that this problem is not only happen in the material, but all the Observable.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedIn.pipe((p) => p);
}
```

run time error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.loggedIn.pipe is not a function
>       at AppComponent.webpackHotUpdate.362.AppComponent.ngOnInit (app.component.ts?a73a:23)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12094)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13597)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13540)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14412)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14353)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:9)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14338)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13507)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14739)

Comment: It all depends upon how you've installed the dependencies and upon the order of any changes to the dependencies in the `package.json` and re-installs/upgrades, etc. Run either `yarn list rxjs` or `npm list rxjs` to see what version(s) of RxJS are in your `node_modules`.

Comment: did you import `pipe`? Or imported complete `rxjs` into the file?

Comment: @cartant I checked my rxjs version is 5.5.2 and material is 5.0.0-rc0

Comment: @sabithpocker Do I really need to do anything on the material js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Richard Matsen's comment, Just use [aspnetcore-angular2-universal](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal)

to start your project with VS2017

Answer (score 1):

The error message is coming from this block of code, at line 180 of [material2/src/lib/form-field/form-field.ts](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/de8c6e28811bf6a05cd0ceff2cb49b50378e1c35/src/lib/form-field/form-field.ts)

```js
// Subscribe to changes in the child control state in order to update the form field UI.
this._control.stateChanges.pipe(startWith(null!)).subscribe(() => {
  this._validatePlaceholders();
  this._syncDescribedByIds();
  this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
});
```

and `this._control` is set from the template at line 157

```js
@ContentChild(MatFormFieldControl) _control: MatFormFieldControl<any>;
```

The first thing to check, did you import `MatInputModule` in app.module.ts?

```js
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ...
    MatInputModule
  ...
]
```

2nd thing to check, did you add the matInput directive,

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Input">
</mat-form-field>
```

If that's ok, could you please add your template code to the question.

Comment: thanks you for your replay, but I found that is not only the material issue, I have updated the question

Comment: Interesting. I don't have the problem with same config, except @angular packages are at 5.0.2 and I don't have the 3 webpack packages.

Comment: webpack package come from the .net angular2 template

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? See [Angular 5 And ASP.NET Core](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-angular5-and-asp-net-core/), looks like it's up-to-date. Sorry, I'm using @angular/cli - no experience using Angular with .net.

Comment: See [aspnetcore-angular2-universal](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal), and his latest fix [fix(webpack): remove AoTPlugin for AngularCompilerPlugin](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal/commit/0ab9dbf1ce7f0255b74f5560e763b568a789865b). He has a similar package.json to yours, and changed @ngtools/webpack handling in webpack.config.js.

Comment: Cheers. I'm presuming it's one of the .net angular references that worked (not my material2 answer)? If so, please post a brief answer of your own and mark it correct instead of my answer. Otherwise, it's confusing for other people searching the same problem.